# JSch scp without known_host file and with StrictHostKeyChecking

Tags: java, scp, jsch, public-key

I am trying to copy some files from a Windows machine to a Linux machine, which is working fine with JSch so far. I can copy files using `StrictHostKeyChecking no` or I need to have the `known_host` file from the Linux machine I copy to. I am using the code for a Java project which should be able to send files automatically to (unknown) Linux machines. I got the username, password, IP and the publickey for the machine. Is there any way to authenticate without the `known_host` file and via the publickey? Because of security issues I do not want to switch `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no` but then I get "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey"

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
JSch jsch = new JSch();

//jsch.setKnownHosts("");
jsch.addIdentity("D:\\Uni\\Arbeit\\remote_id_rsa");
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
//session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.connect();
```

Comment: You don't want to disable host key checking, but you want to connect to a host where you don't have its host key. What role would host key checking serve here? What should jsch do here as a result of the host key check?

Comment: The question was if there is a possibility to connect to a machine by not using jsch.setKnownHosts(""); and not turning StrictHostKeyChecking to no. Because I think it's better to demand for the public/private key than the KnownHostFile in the java programm. I'm really new to JSch and the key authentification, maybe it was hard to get what I really want to do. So one more time, I got username, password and the private/public keypair, is it possible to authenticate with these credentials, so that I don't need to copy the KnownHost file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not make sense. Either you know the host public key and you can verify it either using the `known_host` file or programmatically using:

```
public void KnownHosts.add(HostKey hostkey, UserInfo userinfo)
```

(You can access the instance of `KnownHosts` using `Session.getHostKeyRepository()`)

For more details, see [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)

---

Or you do not know the host public key, and then you cannot create a secure connection (and the `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is your only option).

---

See *my* article about [verifying the host key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key) to understand, what is it about, and its importance. The article is about WinSCP client, but it's valid in general for any SSH client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the private/public keypair, so that I should be able to create a secure connection. But I do not want to use the KnownHost file. If I got you right I need to do it programmatically then. But I don't get how that is supposed to work. First I get the HostKeyRepository by Session.getHostKeyRepository() and then I add the hostkey by public void KnownHosts.add(HostKey hostkey, UserInfo userinfo). How does the session know there is a new key in the repository then?

Comment: The [`HostKey` instance holds "host"](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/HostKey.html) it's to be used with. If that's what you ask for.

Comment: Thanks again, highly apreciate your support. I use rsa public keypair which should be ok for JSch I think,but when I'm running the following I get an invalid keytype exception                           `HostKeyRepository repo = jsch.getHostKeyRepository();  
File file = new File("D:\\Uni\\Arbeit\\remote_id_rsa");
byte[] HK = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
HostKey hk = new HostKey("te2342st", HK); 
repo.add(hk, null);
session.connect();`

Comment: What is `remote_id_rsa`? I'm afraid you are confused or do not understand what different keys are for. A "public keypair" is a nonsense. A keypair contains both public and private key, that's why it is a "pair". Host key repository should include only the public key. While `id_rsa` is a common name given to a private key. Moreover you should not have a server's private key locally, that's a terrible security hole. I would actually say that you have your account private key in the file, not the server's key. Read *my* article [Understanding SSH Key Pairs](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).

Comment: I actually tried both the User public key and User private key. Indeed I did not know there is another key pair for the host, so that I was stuck there. I read your articles about that and gathered some more informations via google. I am already a bit ashamed to ask you another question. In your article "Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?" you say that I need the fingerprint, which should be sth like this _6a:de:e0:af:56:f8:0c:04:11:5b:ef:4d:49:ad:09:23_. So if I got you right that's the host public key? Using fingerprint I still get invalid key type exception...

Comment: The `xx:xx:xx:...` is a host key fingerprint (human readable digest of the key). The JSch `HostKey` needs a full public key. On most Linux servers that use OpenSSH, you will find that in `/root/.ssh/*.pub`. Or use a not-so-secure way to obtain it, as suggested by @Damienknight in his answer.

Comment: Nice I think found the host public key, should be this one _ssh_host_rsa_key.pub_ . There are some other types of the key like dsa or ecdsa but no matter which one I choose I still get the `invalid key type` exception. Is there sth wrong with the code? Because the hostkey should be right now...

Comment: Your follow-up question: [Creating JSch HostKey instance from a public key in .pub format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604333/creating-jsch-hostkey-instance-from-a-public-key-in-pub-format)