# Creating JSch HostKey instance from a public key in .pub format

Tags: java, jsch, public-key

I am trying to send a file from a Windows machine to a Linux machine using JSch. Because of that I copied the host public key from the Linux machine to my Windows machine and added the key to my `HostKeyRepository`. But for some reason I get "invalid key type" exception. Here is my code:

```
HostKeyRepository repo = jsch.getHostKeyRepository();
File file = new File("D:\\Uni\\Arbeit\\ssh_host_rsa_key.pub");
byte[] HK = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(password);  
HostKey hk = new HostKey(null, HK); 
repo.add(hk, null);
session.connect();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.pub` file has format:

```
<type> <base64-encoded-public-key> <comment>
```

What goes to the [`HostKey` constructor](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/HostKey.html#HostKey-java.lang.String-byte:A-) is the public key part only, in a binary form (not base64-encoded).

Use the JSch `Util.fromBase64()` to convert the `base64-encoded-public-key` part to `byte[]`.

```
static byte[] fromBase64(byte[] buf, int start, int length)
```

---

You can also check the JSch implementation of the `known_hosts` file parsing in the `KnownHosts.setKnownHosts(InputStream input)`.

The `known_hosts` file has a similar format as the `.pub` file, except that there's an additional `hostname` part in the front and the `comment` is usually not included:

```
<hostname> <type> <base64-encoded-public-key> [comment]
```

Note that your implementation does not have to be that complex as theirs, if you know that you are going to parse one specific format of the file.

---

So read the line from `File` to string, remove the `<type>` and `<comment>` and use this expression (taken from `KnownHosts.setKnownHosts`, the key is the `<base64-encoded-public-key>` part):

```
Util.fromBase64(Util.str2byte(key), 0, key.length())
```