# How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, public-key

I'm running a java program where I transfer a file from one folder to another, using Java SFTP. The problem I'm having is that  I'm getting the following error in  my Java SFTP (using JSch) :

> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jdk\bin\javaw.exe
>   -server -classpath C:\JDeveloper\mywork\Java_Hello_World.adf;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\Java_Hello_World\Client\classes;C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\jsch-0.1.53.jar
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore5840796204189742395.jks
>   FileTransfer com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: 127.0.0.1.
>   RSA key fingerprint is a2:39:3f:44:88:e9:1f:d7:d1:71:f4:85:98:fb:90:dc
>     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:797)  at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)     at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)     at
>   FileTransfer.main(FileTransfer.java:33) Process exited with exit code
>   0.

The following is my code so far:

```
FileTransfer fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();              

JSch jsch = new JSch();

try {

    String host = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 22;

    String user = "user";
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);      
    session = jsch.getSession("username", "127.0.0.1", 22);
    session.connect();  // bug here , java.net.ConnectException

    ChannelSftp sftp = null;
    sftp = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp") ; //channel;

    //extra config code
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    // end extra config code

    sftp.rename("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Work\\ConnectOne_Bancorp\\Java_Work\\SFTP_1\\house.bmp", "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Work\\ConnectOne_Bancorp\\Java_Work\\SFTP_2\\house.bmp");  
    session.disconnect();

} catch (JSchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (SftpException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} //end-catch
```

My Cygwin is set up, and I checked (with `netstat -a -b` ) that it's running.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are trying to skip a host key checking by setting `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`.

But you have to do that before the checking, i.e. before the `session.connect()`.

---

Anyway, you should never do this, unless you do not care about security. The host key checking is there to protect you from [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Instead, set up an expected host key to let JSch verify it.

For example:

- Call [`JSch.setKnownHosts`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setKnownHosts-java.lang.String-) providing a path to a `.ssh/known_hosts`-like file.

  To generate the `.ssh/known_hosts`-like file, you can use an `ssh-keyscan` command from OpenSSH. If you are connecting from a *nix server, you should have the command available, just run

  ```
  ssh-keyscan example.com > known_hosts
  ```

  It will have a format like:

  ```
  example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA0hVqZOvZ7yWgie9OHdTORJVI5fJJoH1yEGamAd5G3werH0z7e9ybtq1mGUeRkJtea7bzru0ISR0EZ9HIONoGYrDmI7S+BiwpDBUKjva4mAsvzzvsy6Ogy/apkxm6Kbcml8u4wjxaOw3NKzKqeBvR3pc+nQVA+SJUZq8D2XBRd4EDUFXeLzwqwen9G7gSLGB1hJkSuRtGRfOHbLUuCKNR8RV82i3JvlSnAwb3MwN0m3WGdlJA8J+5YAg4e6JgSKrsCObZK7W1R6iuyuH1zA+dtAHyDyYVHB4FnYZPL0hgz2PSb9c+iDEiFcT/lT4/dQ+kRW6DYn66lS8peS8zCJ9CSQ==
  ```

  And reference the generated `known_hosts` file in your JSch code.

  If you are on Windows, you can get a Windows build of `ssh-keyscan` from [Win32-OpenSSH project](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) or Git for Windows.
- Call `JSch.getHostKeyRepository().add()` to provide the expected host key (e.g. hard-coded, as your other credentials).

  See [Creating JSch HostKey instance from a public key in .pub format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29604333/850848).

Answer (score 19):

jsch version : 0.1.55

my problem solved by running :

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa <HOST_NAME> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -t rsa <IP_ADDRESS_OF_HOST_NAME> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

**in my case  jsch was  looking  for ip address in known_hosts file

```
jsch.setKnownHosts(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.ssh/known_hosts");
```

Comment: Appending ~/.ssh/known_host file with the proper hostkeys solved the problem, thank you for the first two comment lines! Jsch will not append the file, you must do that manually. This is the way!

Comment: This also solved the problem for me, not sure why manually SSH'ing into the remote box didn't do it

Answer (score 4):

Aside: by "Cygwin" I assume you mean sshd or sftpd, because Cygwin itself doesn't do SSH.

Anyway, if you want Jsch client to accept any key from the host, move the `.setConfig` calls that sets `StrictHostKeyChecking no` so it is **before** `session.connect()`. Alternatively you must provide access to a store containing the correct key(s) for your hosts(s) as @Martin explains -- and you should always do that when connecting to anything other than "localhost" or possibly a machine certain to be on the same, physically-secure network segment (such as a wired LAN hub within a single room).

Comment: *"you must"*: Please do not suggest anyone not to verify the SSH host key. At least not without explaining the consequences. It's a terrible security mistake.

Comment: what is sftpd by the way?

Comment: @Coffee I meant "any server (in Unix usually something-d) that implements sftp specifically, but not the rest of ssh". For Linux that's usually (not always) vsftpd, but I don't know about cygwin. I probably should have said "an sftp server".

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 For Linux, it's OpenSSH, not vsftpd. The same for Cygwin.