# JSch 0.1.53 session.connect() throws "End of IO Stream Read"

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I downloaded a new [JSch 0.1.53 library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and JSch (sftp) download task no longer works. This release fails on `session.connect()` function throwing an error `Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read`.

My old jsch.jar(2011-10-06) works fine to the same host, maybe I am missing a new config props?

```
Session session=null;
ChannelSftp channel=null;
try {
    JSch.setLogger(SSHUtil.createJschLogger());

    JSch jsch=new JSch();
    session=jsch.getSession("myuser", "11.22.33.44", 22);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 
    session.setPassword("mypwd");
    session.connect(2000); // <-- FAILS HERE
    channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect(2000);
    ...
```

This is an extensive JSch logging indicating whats going on.

```
INFO : Connecting to 11.22.33.44 port 22
INFO : Connection established
INFO : Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
INFO : Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
INFO : CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO : aes256-ctr is not available.
INFO : aes192-ctr is not available.
INFO : aes256-cbc is not available.
INFO : aes192-cbc is not available.
INFO : CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO : diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
INFO : ecdh-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
INFO : ecdh-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
INFO : ecdh-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
INFO : CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO : ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
INFO : ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
INFO : ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO : kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO : kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
INFO : kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO : kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO : kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO : kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO : kex: server:
INFO : kex: server:
INFO : kex: client: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO : kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
INFO : kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO : kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO : kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: client: none
INFO : kex: client: none
INFO : kex: client:
INFO : kex: client:
INFO : kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO : kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<1024) sent
INFO : expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
INFO : Disconnecting from 11.22.33.44 port 22
Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:558)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at my.test.DownloadSFTP.main(DownloadSFTP.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
        at com.jcraft.jsch.IO.getByte(IO.java:84)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:918)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:323)
```

I have also a very old Jsch.jar (2011-10-06) where download task works fine, this is a log. A Reason I wanted to upgrade is this very slow transferring files. New release should do things better I have read.

```
INFO : Connecting to 11.22.33.44 port 22
INFO : Connection established
INFO : Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
INFO : Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.44
INFO : CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO : aes256-ctr is not available.
INFO : aes192-ctr is not available.
INFO : aes256-cbc is not available.
INFO : aes192-cbc is not available.
INFO : arcfour256 is not available.
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO : kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO : kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO : expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO : ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN : Permanently added '11.22.33.44' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO : Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO : Next authentication method: publickey
INFO : Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO : Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO : Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
INFO : Disconnecting from 11.22.33.44 port 22
INFO : Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to socket closed
```

**EDIT**
I had an idea to backstep releases in a [Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.jcraft%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsch%22) and actually it is this very new release not working properly. Previous jsch-0.1.52.jar release works fine. I try to contact library developers.

This is a log from a working 0.1.52 release.

```
INFO : Connecting to 11.22.33.44 port 22
INFO : Connection established
INFO : Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
INFO : Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.52
INFO : CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO : aes256-ctr is not available.
INFO : aes192-ctr is not available.
INFO : aes256-cbc is not available.
INFO : aes192-cbc is not available.
INFO : CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO : diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
INFO : ecdh-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
INFO : ecdh-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
INFO : ecdh-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
INFO : CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO : ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
INFO : ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
INFO : ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO : kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO : kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
INFO : kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO : kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO : kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO : kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO : kex: server:
INFO : kex: server:
INFO : kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO : kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
INFO : kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO : kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO : kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO : kex: client: none
INFO : kex: client: none
INFO : kex: client:
INFO : kex: client:
INFO : kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO : kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO : SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO : expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO : ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN : Permanently added '11.22.33.44' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO : Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO : Next authentication method: publickey
INFO : Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO : Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO : Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JSch 0.1.53 supports (and prefers) the `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` KEX, what the server claims to support too, so the JSch tries to use it.

For some reason the server disconnects you afterwards.

To workaround that, force the JSch to use the `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` KEX, what the JSch 0.1.52 prefers:

```
session.setConfig("kex", "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1");
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). For the correct (and secure) approach, see: [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl facing the same problem but with Apache VFS in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44076349/3231778).

Answer (score 2):

I had an same problem i just changed the jsch version to 0.1.54 and got solved

**add this to your pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue with 0.1.54 version too.("End of IO Stream Read")

Comment: check with higher version. @sharathchandra

Comment: Same error is coming with the higher version too

Answer (score 2):

After trying out many solutions, below solved my issue

- Open ssh server's sshd_config in a text editor and add below
  line to the end of the file:

  ```
  KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  ```
- After editing the file ensure you restart you ssh service

Answer (score 0):

> INFO : SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<1024) sent

It indicates you have max key length is 1024
as it failed in https://github.com/is/jsch/blob/addb8e3a0ebd71cbbf51cf6ba746e8e128df713c/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/DHGEX.java#L240

The server expects key length of 2048 or more perhaps. Hence disconnecting.

1)Reduce min key length on the server to 1024
OR

2)Disable diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
https://github.com/is/jsch/blob/addb8e3a0ebd71cbbf51cf6ba746e8e128df713c/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.java#L60

3)Try : https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.mwiede/jsch