# how can i download a file from sshd server to jsch client properly mobile to mobile

Tags: java, android, jsch, sshd, apache-sshd

i have a sshd server running on my mobile without error i am trying to download a file from my mobile internal storage using jsch as client . getting this errors

** CLIENT **

```
    public void startClient(){

   String localFile = "/data/user/0/com.open.jsch/databases/au.au_1";
    String remoteFile = "/data/user/0/com.open.androidsshd/databases/au.au_1";

    Session jschSession = null;

    try {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    jsch.setKnownHosts("/home/mkyong/.ssh/known_hosts");
    jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT);

    // authenticate using private key
    // jsch.addIdentity("/home/mkyong/.ssh/id_rsa");

    // authenticate using password
    jschSession.setPassword(PASSWORD);

    //Missing code
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    jschSession.setConfig(config);
    //
    System.out.println("Establishing connection");
    // 10 seconds session timeout
    jschSession.connect(SESSION_TIMEOUT);

    Channel sftp = jschSession.openChannel("sftp");

    // 5 seconds timeout
    sftp.connect(CHANNEL_TIMEOUT);

    ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) sftp;

    // transfer file from local to remote server
    //channelSftp.put(localFile, remoteFile);

    // download file from remote server to local
    channelSftp.get(remoteFile, localFile);
    System.out.println("got the file");
    channelSftp.exit();

    } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
    if (jschSession != null) {
        jschSession.disconnect();
    }
    }


   }
```

**Client Error**

```
    2022-10-30 21:55:59.228 15159-15202/com.allah.jsch W/System.err: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:     Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    2022-10-30 21:55:59.228 15159-15202/com.allah.jsch W/System.err:     at  com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
    2022-10-30 21:55:59.228 15159-15202/com.allah.jsch W/System.err:     at com.allah.jsch.Client.startClient(Client.java:71)
    2022-10-30 21:55:59.228 15159-15202/com.allah.jsch W/System.err:     at com.allah.jsch.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:78)
    2022-10-30 21:55:59.229 15159-15202/com.allah.jsch W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**SERVER**

```
int port = 8888;
SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
sshd.setPort(port);
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(
    "src/test/resources/hostkey.ser"));
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Arrays
    .<NamedFactory<Command>>asList(new SftpSubsystem.Factory()));
sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());
sshd.setShellFactory(new EchoShellFactory()); // necessary if you want to type commands over ssh
sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {

@Override
public boolean authenticate(String u, String p, ServerSession s) {
    return ("sftptest".equals(u) && "sftptest".equals(p));


}


});


try {
sshd.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

for client side testing. i am running on my android studio emulator .for server i am running on mobile. for the first time i run the code there is a lots of error but i fixed it by adding dependencies and internet permission whatever i can find it online  now the errors i cant fixit there is no answers on the google or stack i an understanding  i need help

**permission **

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**gradle on client **

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sshd/sshd-core
implementation group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-core', version: '0.6.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple
testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.2'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16
implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk16', version: '1.46'
```

```
    implementation files('libs\\jsch-0.1.55.jar')
```

i am expecting to download a file from SSHD server to JSCH client/ SSHD Client . i think i am missing some code on server side i need some help with this . i know you guys are very busy please a humble request give me a correct working solution thanks for advance

Comment: So your server is running on an Android device. Ok. And where is your client running?

Comment: I don't have two device currently so client run on windows Android studio pixel 3 device emulator

Comment: And how is a connection established between the 'devices'? Wifi? Or mobile connection of Android device? Please explain your setup to the point.

Comment: Which ip is used by the client to connect to the server? Or how are you trying?

Comment: for server i am using mobile network 4G . for client my desktop connected to a broadband connection via ethernet cable

Comment: Context context = MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext();
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

Comment: i am getting the ip of my server mobile by above codeand server port sett to 8888 , then i use that ip and port number 8888 on the client side . i am using the port 8888 because i am not able to connect port 22 getting error any port below 1024  unless both device rooted

Comment: File path = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("au.au_1");                                            
Log.d("T", String.valueOf(path));   i use this line of code to get the path of my storage i don't know is this the right way

Comment: You should put all code readable in you post. No in a comments.

Comment: That code is messing around with wifi manager and will not give you mobile/public/internet ip of your Android device. So useless. You did not tell which ip you actually got.

Comment: "192.168.1.39" this is the ip i got

Comment: Well you could comment on that ip. Why didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short:

Even if you would manage to determine the public internet ip of your Android device that ip would be useless as most mobile providers block incoming connections.

Hence it makes no sense trying your mobile phone to act as a server.

Only possible on wifi.

Comment: ok then two Wi-Fi connected mobile phone then . i have only one broad band internet connection if i connect two mobile to same Wi-Fi  will it work how can i debug the app

Comment: Are both devices connected to the same wifi? I mean to the same router? You do not need internet connections if both devices use your wif router.

Comment: And then: if the server has local lan ip 192.168.1.39 then the client should use that ip to connect.

Comment: most mobile providers block incoming connections.  so then how anydesk kind of app works and  i am running a torrent on my mobile this kind of app use some kind of incoming connection right

Comment: i like to know my server or client code is ok ?

Comment: Can you stay to the point please? We first wanna know if your client can connect if you use that ip. And you did not even comment on that ip although asked.

Comment: the first time  asked about the ip i gave u code because that where i got the ip . i thought maybe that's not the way to get the ip .if i gave u a Radom number like  192.168.1.39 how can u figure out the problem that what i am thinking .  i am really sorry

Comment: i tried to run server on a nexus  ipServer 192.168.232.2  then tried to connect server with client with pixel 3a ipClient 10.0.2.16  i got a time out error W/System.err: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established

Comment: Those ip's are so different that clearly both devices do not use the same wifi network.

Comment: Your client should try to connect to the 33. Not to the 36 as the 36 is the client itself if i have to believe you.

Comment: i fixed it now ipServer 192.168.1.33 / ipClient 192.168.1.36 W/System.err: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read

Comment: So you could establish a connection. Great!

Comment: i tried to serch the error i found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280442/jsch-0-1-53-session-connect-throws-end-of-io-stream-read                   i change this session conifg like this  session.setConfig("kex", "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1");   same error