# JSch PAM authentication - "Auth fail" - credentials are correct

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, pam

I'm building an SFTP class responsible for listing the files of a remote directory. I'm using the JSch library to do so. I have a user set up already, and I can manually SSH to the remote server just fine. However, when JSch attempts to connect it responds with

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

One thing I noticed though; when I manually SSH onto the server, I see that it's using "PAM Authentication." What am I missing?

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
Session session = jSch.getSession(username, destination, port);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PAM authentication on server-side, it's probable that you need to implement the keyboard-interactive authentication on client-side.

See [What's the difference between “password” and “keyboard-interactive”?](https://superuser.com/q/894608/213663) question to understand the relation between PAM and keyboard-interactive authentication.

---

For keyboard-interactive authentication implementation example, see the [official `UserAuthKI` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthKI.java.html).

Basically you need to implement the [`UIKeyboardInteractive` interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UIKeyboardInteractive.html) (together with the [`UserInfo` interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html)) and associate the implementation with the session using the [`Session.setUserInfo`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setUserInfo-com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo-).

If the authentication is prompting for a single "password" only, implement the [`UIKeyboardInteractive.promptKeyboardInteractive` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UIKeyboardInteractive.html#promptKeyboardInteractive-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-boolean:A-) to return a single element array with the password.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). For the correct (and secure) approach, see: [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)*

Answer (score 1):

Below code is tested and working as expected for me. Just try below code:

```
 /**
     * Transfer a file to remote destination via JSCH library using sFTP protocol
     * 
     * @param username String remote SFTP server user name.
     * @param password String remote SFTP server user password
     * @param host String remote SFTP server IP address or host name.
     * @param file File to transfer to SFTP Server.
     * @param transferProtocol protocol to transfer a file. {@link FileTransferProtocol}
     * @return boolean true if file is transfered otherwise false.
     * @throws ApplicationException
     */
    public static boolean transferFile(final String username, final String password, final String host,
                                       final File file, final FileTransferProtocol transferProtocol) {
  //      throws ApplicationException {
        // currently can deal with sftp only.
 //       LOGGER.trace("Invoking transferFile...");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host);
 //           LOGGER.debug("Session Host: " + session.getHost());
            session.setPassword(password);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(properties);
 //           LOGGER.debug("Connecting to a session Host Server...");
            session.connect();
 //           LOGGER.debug("session is established with host server.");
 //           Channel channel = session.openChannel(transferProtocol.ftpStringRepresentation());
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
 //           LOGGER.debug("Connecting to a sftp Channel...");
            channel.connect();
 //           LOGGER.debug("Connected with sftp Channel.");
            ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());
 //           LOGGER.debug("File transfered successfully");
            channelSftp.exit();
 //           LOGGER.debug("sftp channel disconnected.");
            channel.disconnect();
 //           LOGGER.debug("channel disconnected.");
            session.disconnect();
  //          LOGGER.debug("session disconnected.");
            return true;
        } catch (JSchException | FileNotFoundException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
//            throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage(), ApplicationSeverity.ERROR, e.getCause(), e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

URL: https://github.com/SanjayMadnani/com.sanjay.common.common-utils/blob/master/common-utils/src/main/java/com/sanjay/common/util/FileUtil.java

Comment: pass `null ` value for `transferProtocol`.

Comment: -1 - How can this answer help the OP? Your code is identical to the question + Never ever suggest anyone to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` without explaining the consequences!