# "reject HostKey" when connecting to remote host through jumphost with JSch

Tags: java, unix, ssh, jsch, portforwarding

Need to SSH to destination host through jumphost. Had tried the same mentioned in [JSch JumpHosts example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html).

```
Session[] sessions = new Session[2];
Session session = null;

sessions[0] = session = jsch.getSession(getUserName(), "jumphost1.com", 22);
session.setPassword(getHostPassword());
UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
userInfo.setPassword(getHostPassword());
session.setUserInfo(userInfo);
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
prop.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
session.setConfig(prop);
session.connect();

String host = "host1.com";
int assignedPort = session.setPortForwardingL(0, host, 22);
LOGGER.info("Jump host the {} of agent {} and port forwarding {}", i, host, assignedPort);

sessions[i] = session = jsch.getSession(getUserName(), "127.0.0.1", assignedPort);
session.setPassword(getHostPassword());
userInfo = new UserInfo();
userInfo.setPassword(getHostPassword());
session.setUserInfo(userInfo);
session.setHostKeyAlias(host);
session.connect();
```

Getting below exception when connection to destination host:

```
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: 127.0.0.1
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:799)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:345)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

I am trying to login to host `host1.com` through `jumphost1.com`

- login to `jumphost1.com`
- then ssh `host1.com`
- execute the commands in the `host1`

Comment: I don't know jsch, but from what you're saying `127.0.0.1` in your `jsch.getSession(...)` has nothing to do here and should probably be `jumphost1.com` or maybe `host1.com`

Comment: JSCH is java library , Have refered the below example http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html

Comment: Alright nevermind, your code seems consistent with the example (connect to a first server, then get a session on `127.0.0.1` from this one). I'll have to let someone familiar with the tool answer, good luck !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code for connecting through jumphost is correct.

The only problem is that your local host key repository contains a different host key for the second host, than what you receive from the real (second) host.

You actually do not seem to **care about security**, as you set `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` for the jumphost session (what the [official example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html) rightly does not do!). But you do not do the same for the second session, hence the error.

See also [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)

Comment: this localhost mean jumphost1.com,so which will have already knowhost added. please correct me if i wrong.  Also i should be able to use ChannelExec in destination host?

Comment: Also trying to understand first step where generating knownhost, I have to run the ssh-keyscan command in all the host and have in the file? bcoz i have few server which uses different jumphost , so i have generate and map the same in file and upload?

Comment: I tried setting StrictHostKeyChecking=no for second session , but if gives me Auth Cancel error Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel

Comment: OK, so the problem is solved, as you got past a host key verification! Though have to repeat that by setting `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` **you give up on security**! - Anyway, you have another problem now - authentication. One obvious problem is, that you use password instead of username: `jsch.getSession(getHostPassword(), ...)`