# How to generate known_host file in windows machine

Tags: ssh, jsch, ssh-keys

I am using Jsch(Jcraft) library to establish a SSH connection with a SSH server as shown below :

```
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        String user = "****";
        String host = "****";
        int port = 22;
        String privateKey = "***.ppk";//Path to private key(The file is in .ppk format)
        try 
        {
            jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
            sftpChannel.connect();
            /*file transfer code*/
            sftpChannel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The SSH connection is successfully established as "StrictHostKeyChecking" is disabled. If its enabled I get the following error :

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: ******. RSA key f
 is *************
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:805)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:345)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

I understand we need to set know host file in the code as shown below :

```
jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHostsFileName);
```

I am unable to generate known_hosts file via the command below :

```
ssh-keyscan <HOST> > known_hosts
```

It is throwing the following error :

```
'ssh-keyscan' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have only public and private keys in .ppk format. I dont have the known_host file.
 How do we create known_host file? 
 Why is **ssh-keyscan** command throwing error - not recognized as internal/external command?

Comment: Do you mean creating it programmatically, or interactively? This file is supposed to be created based on the human user's trust of the SSH host, in most cases.

Comment: Not programmatically. How to create it interactively? And When does this get created?

Comment: *"is not working"* is not working as a problem description.

Comment: My Apologies.I just to want to convey that when I run ssh-keyscan command in windows command line, I get error 'ssh-keyscan' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: My answer to the duplicate question shows how to get `ssh-keyscan` for Windows. Read the answer carefully, before asking new questions.

Comment: Why you keep editing your question, if you already have the answer?

Comment: I unable to generate known_host file via ssh-keyscan command that's why edited the question.

Comment: All you have told us so far, is that you get *"'ssh-keyscan' is not recognized as an internal or external command..."* - What is expected as you are on Windows, where `ssh-keyscan` is not present by default. You have to install it. And how to install is it is show in [my answer to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848#32858953), as I have commented above already! What do you need to know more?

Comment: Understood. I need to install OpenSSH server on windows to run ssh-keyscan.

Answer (score 4):

`ssh-keyscan` is a command from Linux/Unix. In order to execute it on Windows, you need a version that has been modified to run on Windows. Easiest is to install [git-for-windows](/questions/tagged/git-for-windows)([download](https://gitforwindows.org/)) and open `Git Bash`. Inside this console you can use the `ssh-keyscan` command.

Answer (score 1):

This file is typically created either by `ssh-keyscan`, or by the user's connection to the SSH host.

You can simply create it by the command

```
ssh-keyscan [host]
```

and save the output.  The `-H` option enables hashed output but I don't know if the library in question can use it.

Notice that the `known_hosts` file by itself is not very useful without having verified the host fingerprints first.  The following caution is straight from the `ssh-keyscan` man page:

> ```
> SECURITY
>      If an ssh_known_hosts file is constructed using ssh-keyscan without veri-
>      fying the keys, users will be vulnerable to man in the middle attacks.
>      On the other hand, if the security model allows such a risk, ssh-keyscan
>      can help in the detection of tampered keyfiles or man in the middle
>      attacks which have begun after the ssh_known_hosts file was created
> ```

Comment: Does this command work in Windows OS? I am getting error 'ssh-keyscan' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you're using OpenSSH or a variant, yes. Check "PATH" environment variable?

Comment: ssh-keyscan <host IP addess> from windows command prompt is not working. It is throwing error 'ssh-keyscan' is not recognized as a command. What do I need to check in Path environment variable?

Comment: `ssh-keyscan` ignores `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config`, and some hosts I'm trying to connect to are behind a proxy.

Comment: In Windows 10, you can add Open SSH Client from Settings -> Apps -> Optional features. This gets you both `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-keyscan`. 
After running keygen & uploading the public key file to the host I want to connect to as per their instructions, in a cmd prompt in my .ssh directory, I ran `ssh-keyscan [host] > known_hosts`. I could then connect automagically from a simple python script using `pysftp`.