# Does JSch need sftp/ssh client installed

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch to transfer a file to a remote server. I have configured it to use sftp channel with user/password and StrictHostKeyChecking set to 'no'. Since I have open channel set to sftp, does JSch require sftp/ssh client to be installed on the client machine?

Comment: No. it implementation of SSH.

Comment: Obligatory warning: Do not set `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` - you are losing security by doing so. See [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)

Answer (score 3):

No,JSch is a pure Java implementation of SSH2.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/