# JSch is deleting file from server after download

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using Jsch to copy a file from the server. My code is:

```
log.debug("private key path: " + sftpPrivateKey);
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.setKnownHosts(sftpKnownHost);
jsch.addIdentity(sftpPrivateKey, sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase);
Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(sftpUser, sftpHost, sftpPort);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
jschSession.setConfig(config);
jschSession.connect();
ChannelSftp channelSftp  = (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
channelSftp.connect();
channelSftp.cd(fileLocation);
channelSftp.get(scrOnDirectory, desOnLocalSystem);
```

but after the download (e.i. `channelSftp.get()`), it's deleting file from the server, which I don't want. I need to copy-paste file not cut-paste file.

Answer (score 2):

JSch `ChannelSftp.get` does not delete the file from the server.

If the file is deleted, it must be a feature of the server, that it deletes any file that is downloaded. Try to download the file using a GUI/commandline SFTP client to check if you get the same behaviour.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). For the correct (and secure) approach, see: [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)*